# Update EF ICollection property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, one-to-many

How do I update a ICollection property in EF?

I get this error message;

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to '`System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MySolution.Domain.UserProfile>`'"

My entities:

```
public class Department
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string DepartmentTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }

}

public class UserProfile
{
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

Code;

```
    var userProfile = _db.UserProfiles.Single(d => d.UserName == "SomeUserName");

    var department = _db.Departments.Single(d => d.Id == variableDepartmentID);
    department.UserProfiles = uProfile.UserId;
    _db.UpdateDepartment(department);
    _db.Save();
```

Comment: `department.UserId = uProfile.UserId;` so... where is UserId property in Department??

Comment: I think you want `department.UserProfiles.Add(uProfile);` but its a bit hard to tell from your example what your intent is. I wrote up a bit of a tutorial on how to use nav properties which you may find helpful: http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/07/entity-framework-navigation-property.html Its a broad overview on how they work and how to use them

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! It's supposed to be 'department.UserProfiles' and not 'department.UserId'. I've corrected the code above now. And of course it's here where it doesn't work out well. The property UserProfiles is ICollection and my question is how I add a new value to a property like that. Actually a foreign key in the UserProfiles table. A very simple move normally, but how do I go about it here?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry again. I missed your entry Luke McGregor. Thanks! I got it. It worked out perfect!

Comment: This was very strange. Your guideance Luke worked out in the way that data was updated, but it still throw an error message: "An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details"

Comment: The error came from a mess in my code. Here is the corrected code:"var userProfile = _db.UserProfiles.Single(d => d.UserName == vUserName);
                    var department = _db.Departments.Single(d => d.Id == vDepartment);
                    department.UserProfiles.Add(userProfile);
                    _db.UpdateDepartment(department);
                    _db.Save();"